# Error accessing inherited properties/methods with EL

Tags: java, generics, jsf, tree, richfaces

I am trying to get a generic tree backing-bean to work. I have one generic class called ACLTree, and then an implementation of it.
In my JSF document I try to access a value per #{mybackingbean.property}.
But I get an ELException:

```
javax.el.ELException: /modules/useradmin/acl.xhtml @30,55 value="#{ACOTree.root}": java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class de.xy.jsf.beans.ACLTree with modifiers "public"
```

I am not very familiar with the concepts of generics and the reflection api, so maybe it's simply not possible.

stack trace:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.ELException: /modules/useradmin/rights.xhtml @30,55 value="#{ACOTree.root}": java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class de.xy.jsf.beans.ACLTree with modifiers "public"
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:580)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.getValue(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:1647)
        at org.richfaces.component.UITree.createDataModel(UITree.java:679)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:621)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:339)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.TreeRendererBase.writeContent(TreeRendererBase.java:688)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.TreeRendererBase.encodeChildren(TreeRendererBase.java:629)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:827)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:200)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:195)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:827)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:233)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:270)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:827)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:883)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:137)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:827)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:279)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.TabRendererBase.encodeChildren(TabRendererBase.java:149)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:827)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:266)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:261)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:827)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:883)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:889)
        at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:578)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:108)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:266)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:159)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at cz.softeu.rewriter.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /modules/useradmin/rights.xhtml @30,55 value="#{ACOTree.root}": java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class de.christianvette.boombox.jsf.beans.ACLTree with modifiers "public"
        at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:76)
        at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:577)
        ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class de.xy.jsf.beans.ACLTree with modifiers "public"
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:95)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
        at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:58)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
        ... 76 more
```

the generic class:

```
abstract class ACLTree<T>{
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ACLTree.class);

public TreeNodeImpl<NodeData> root = null;
public TreeNodeImpl<NodeData> nodes = new TreeNodeImpl<NodeData>();

public ACLTree() {
    log.debug("constructor of generic class");
}

public TreeNodeImpl<NodeData> getNodes() {
    return nodes;
}

public void setNodes(TreeNodeImpl<NodeData> nodes) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
}

public TreeNodeImpl<NodeData> getRoot() {
    log.debug("Entering getRoot()");
    if(root == null) buildTree();
    return root;
}

public void setRoot(TreeNodeImpl root) {
    this.root = root;
}

public TreeNodeImpl createTreeNode(ACLObject item) {

}

abstract Collection<T> getData();
```

}

implementation:

```
public class ACOTree extends ACLTree<ACO>{

    @Override
    public Collection<ACO> getData() {
         return AclManagerImpl.getInstance().getAllACOs();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ACOTree` defined as? Does it have a getter for the property you're trying to access? (i.e. `root`)

Comment: ACOTree extends a generic class called ACLTree, so getter and setter are defined in the generic class (as public) and only inherited in ACOTree.

Comment: Which EL implementation/version are you using? Or if you aren't using a specific one, which servletcontainer impl/version are you using? If you also don't know that, just update your question to include the complete stacktrace.

Comment: In my classpath there is EL-impl-1.0 which comes as a dependency of richfaces. The app is running on glassfish 3.

Comment: I see. But there's something unclear. Normally you get this kind of exception whenever the class is created as an **anonymous class**, but the classname in the exception message doesn't give that away (you should have seen something like `ACLTree$1` with the `$n` part). Can you please update your question to include a snippet how an instance of the class is been created?

Comment: ACLTree is abstract. And ACOTree is defined as a managed-bean(request scope).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this problem myself. The problem is the declaration of the abstract class must be public.

For example:

```
public abstract class ACLTree<T>{...}
```

This is because while the method of the abstract class may be public it cannot be accessed from outside its package unless the class is marked public as well.

Comment: I had this same problem, and was very relieved to find the solution was so simple. Thank you.

Comment: 4 hours, at this point I've lost 4 hours, and FINALLY solution - thank you!